# SORT & SPLIT File based on dynamic key value

Tags: bash, shell, file, sorting

I have this sample of *FILE*:

```
Rec 1 20014567  
Rec 1 20014567  
Rec 1 20014567  
Rec 1 20014577  
Rec 1 20014577  
Rec 1 20014577  
Rec 1 20014577  
Rec 1 20014587 
.
.
.
```

I need to split this file depending on the these requirements :

- Key field is from position 11 to 14
- Files will be sorted on this key
- Name the output file with the key name

Output *File1*:

```html
Rec 1 20014567  
Rec 1 20014567  
Rec 1 20014567
```

Output *File2*:

```html
Rec 1 20014577  
Rec 1 20014577  
Rec 1 20014577  
Rec 1 20014577
```

Output *File3*:

```html
Rec 1 20014587
```

I found that this:

```
 sort -k 11.STARTPOS,14.ENDPOS
```

...can be a way to sort by position, but not to filter by files.

Need your help in solving this.

Comment: So the name of the first output file is "14567", is that correct?

Comment: @Beta from 11 to 14 , so the name might be 4567

Comment: It's good form to say "thanks for catching that error, I'll edit".

Comment: @Beta thanks for catching that error, I've edited it

Comment: @EricRenouf I found that this `sort -k 11.STARTPOS,14.ENDPOS` can be a way to sort by position , but not to filter by files

Comment: Do you have any preference about tools, e.g. bash vs. awk?

Comment: @Beta thanks for the reply ,  Actually no I have no preferences

Comment: The task is to iterate through the lines of the file, determine the name of the output file, and write the line to that file. Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: @Beta the iteration and writing lines to the file depending on the key value  , thats what cause me a headache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
awk '{print $0 >>substr($0,11,4)".txt"}' infile.txt
```

That will print the full record ($0) to a file that is named according to the substring of the record from position 11 for 4 characters.

Using the `>>` to Append the data to the files, this way there is no need for sort. If you want the data sorted in each file, then just run the sort command first and pipe that to this awk script. Super simple.

Comment: I have injected your code inside a script file , but it shows this error : `awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file \`infile.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)`, please do have any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Is the file you are monkeying with called "infile.txt". If so, is it in the same folder that you are in when you run that script? If not, you'll have to use the full path.